# this.User.Identity.Name from web.config or database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently I'm doing a check  :

```
@if(this.User.Identity.Name=="DOMAIN\\USERID"){
```

This works great but I'd like to have multiple users(2-3) to check for.  I'd also like to not have it hard coded.  Is there a way to do this in the web.config or in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a list in the config...`User1,User2` etc and then use `linq` and `.Any()` against this list?

```
    var users = "user1,user2,user3".Split(','); //list will come from your config
    bool result = users.Any(u => u == this.User.Identity.Name);
```

Also, since you're using MVC, if you want to use `authorization` for `controllers` etc, you can use the [[Authorize]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attribute. See this SO link too [Authorize attribute in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848086/authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use roles instead then add the relevant users to that role? This would make it easier to expand on in the future, plus you don't have to hard code a list of users.