# IsPostBack on page that requires authentification

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I have an asp.net code behind file with the following code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
```

The piece of code that comes after is used to render some controls and should only be visible to authenticated users; I'm using asp.net Identity.

My question is this: should I leave my code as is or would it be more secure to rewrite it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
```

Comment: You could decorate it with `[Authorize]`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848086/authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Is a postback possible for an unauthenticated user? If so, you should probably leave it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Simply best in second way , Because if the user does authenticate, then only hit next code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
```

I have write this code, like asp.net page life cycle

S **ILVER**

- I-Init
- L-Load
- V-Validation
- E-Event
- R-Rendering

So the code look like the better approach is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//Load
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)//Validation
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
              //Rendering
              .
              .
              .
              .
```

Comment: interesting term: **S ILVER**, +1