# What do the brackets in "[Authorize(Roles = ADMIN)]" mean in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, directive

I get the idea that the controller is checking (somewhere) for the actual user roles, but what do those square brackets mean?

It looks like some kind of directive, but i could not find neither who parses this directive nor where the Authorize function is defined.

Comment: Check this out: [Authorize attribute in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848086/authorize-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Editted back to "ASP.NET" in the title because someone that is searching for that in an ASP.NET page might not know it is from C#, as i also had trouble to find it.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Those who provided answers and links in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the syntax for an [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) in C#:

> Attributes can be placed on most any declaration, though a specific attribute might restrict the types of declarations on which it is valid. In C#, you specify an attribute by placing the name of the attribute, **enclosed in square brackets ([])**, above the declaration of the entity to which it applies.

So what you have is an [`AuthorizeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) on your controller. This is a kind of [action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The ASP.NET / MVC runtime is who "checks" and enforces action filters.

Answer (score 1):

The `Authorize` attribute is actually `AuthorizeAttribute`. That may help your searches. The brackets are a directive that means that the stuff inside is an attribute. Attributes are processed differently based on what they're wrapping. In the case of `AuthorizeAttribute` it's hooking into the request and running it's own code before the action's code runs.